# custom UIButton image is getting reduced (shrinked) in iphone OS 4.0

Tags: image, uibutton

I am facing very  strange issue.

When I was running my app in iPhone OS 3.2 the image which i have set for custom UIButton was looking like : (see attached image.) But when i tried to run the same project with iPhone OS 4.0 the image is changed.

[alt text http://grab.by/5mes](http://grab.by/5mes)

[alt text http://grab.by/5met](http://grab.by/5met)

Can anybody figure it out, what 's the issue.
I also tried to set background image instead of setImage. But result is same.

for 3.2 & before its looking fine but in 4.O the image is shrinked in the same custom button everywhere like the image i have attached.

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check with images those you are setting to UIButtons.
Please make sure images should not contains blank borders.

Comment: Hi Niraj. Thanks for your reply. The problem was with Image only. No iPhone OS issue. Thanks again...