# UIButton Shrinking on iPad OS 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton, uiimage

I am running into an issue with a custom UIButton Image and my iPads 2/3:

**The Problem**

I create a button from an image that is size 72 x 72 px. I set a button frame to the same size of the image. When I run the code in iOS simulator a 72 x 72 px button appears (scaled at 50%). However, when I run the code on my iPad the button is scaled down from 72 x 72 px to approximately 45 x 45 px? When I take a screenshot of the iPad screen, the correct size of 72 x 72 px is shown when scaled to 50% I need the button to be 72 x 72 px on the iPad, how can it be fixed? or can it be fixed? Is an image automatically scaled because of the size of the device?

**Fix Attempts**

1. I added a 2x image to accommodate retina, makes the image bigger but not 72 x 72
2. I changed the resolution of the images from 300 dpi to 72 dpi and no change.
3. Looked at this solution: [UIButton Shrinking Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522034/uibutton-shrinking-image). My image has has an alpha channel, so there was no fix
4. Looked at this solution: [custom UIButton image is getting reduced (shrinked) in iphone OS 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219134/custom-uibutton-image-is-getting-reduced-shrinked-in-iphone-os-4-0). As far as I know, my image does not have any blank borders

**Materials**

iPad 3 (retina) running iOS 7.0 /iPad 2 running ios 7.1.1

Images: RedTarget.png / RedTarget@2x.png

- Dimensions: 72 x 72 px  / 144 x 144 px
- Resolution: 299 pixels/inch
- Alpha Channel: Yes
- Color Space: RGB

**Simple Code Used**

```
UIImage *img;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedTarget@2x.png"];
}
else
{
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedTarget.png"];
    
}
    
CGFloat h =  img.size.height;
CGFloat w =  img.size.width;

UIButton* targetbutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(512,384, w, h)];

NSLog(@"%f %f", w,  h);

[targetbutton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

targetbutton.center = CGPointMake(512,384);   

NSLog(@"%@", targetbutton);

[self.view addSubview:targetbutton];
```

When I run this code on my iPad 3, the NSLog statements print as the following:

```
2014-05-14 10:19:40.511 TestSizeButton[574:60b] 144.000000 144.000000
2014-05-14 10:19:40.515 TestSizeButton[574:60b] <UIButton: 0x16d495a0; frame = (440 312; 144 144); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x16d49730>>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: maybe... autolayout is `ON`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your button at viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method and check whether if it further shrinks or not. Also check whether the position of view is shifting or not while loading. If your view is shifting then add this in your viewDidLoad method

```
if( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)] )
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: The button is not shifting and has always been in the viewDidAppear method.